# Последнее китайское предупреждение

Tags: фразеология

Так говорят, если я не ошибаюсь, когда хотят дать понять, что на самом деле оно никакое не последнее. Но, так или иначе, откуда пошла эта поговорка, никто не подскажет?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

После Второй Мировой войны, в Китае возобновилась гражданская война, в ходе которой почти всю территорию Китая стало контролировать коммунистическое правительство во главе с Мао Цзедуном. Его противники, во главе с с Чан Кай Ши сбежали на Тайвань. С точки зрения самих тайванцев, они были единственными законными представителями правительства Китая, а остальная часть страны - оккупирована коммунистами. На материковом Китае считали наоборот. Как бы то ни было, соцлагерь поддержал КНР, а США со своими союзниками - Тайвань. Последний до 1971 года являлся представителем Китая в ООН. США активно помогал островному правительству, в том, числе и военным присутствием. Также осуществлял воздушную разведку на территории континентального Китая. Китай все эти нарушения суверенитета страны фиксировал, и посылал Америке "серьёзные предупреждения" о недопустимости подобных действий.

"Первое серьезное предупреждение" правительство КНР сделало 7 сентября 1958 г., когда Пекин заявил США протест против конвоирования (охраны) американским военно-морским флотом морских транспортов Тайваня. К середине 1960-х гг. таких "серьезных предупреждений" насчитывалось уже более 400, и они воспринимались всеми только иронически, поскольку реально помешать сотрудничеству США и Тайваня Китай был не в силах. Об этих "предупреждениях", с сообщениями их порядкового номера сообщалось и в советских СМИ (у нас как раз в это время ухудшились отношения с КНР). Дополнительной популяризации выражения послужили конфликт по поводу пограничных островов на Амуре, когда со стороны Китая тоже были похожие предупреждения, правда на этот раз одними предупреждениями дело не ограничилось (конфликт на острове Даманский).

Используются различные варианты этого крылатого выражения, например: "647-е китайское предупреждение", "723-е, последнее, китайское предупреждение" и т. п.

Comment: Мне очень понравился ответ Марка.

Comment: Нажмите на палец, поднятый вверх.

Answer (score 0):

"Тайваньской" предыстории этой идиомы я не знаю, очень возможно, что оно так и было. 
Но есть сомнения в том плане, что выражение русское (или хорошо прижившееся), а в СССР до Тайваня дела особого не было. Зато хорошо помню, как с середины 60-х в Советских газетвх обсуждали "последние китайские предупреждения", выносимые Китаем СССР по разным поводам. Самое смешное, что они были как две капли воды похожи на многочисленные "ТАСС уполномочен заявить", в каковых представлялась точка зрения СССР на его "внутренние дела в любой точки земного щара". Вот только слово "последние" в тассовках обычно не фигурировало.

Comment: Если ваш возраст в профиле указан верно, то непосредственно судить о реакции на события времён вашего младенчества вы вряд ли можете. Все же словари ведут отсчёт выражению именно от тайваньского вопроса.